# Can an ac signal pass from ground( earth's surface) to the socket?

Tags: tester

My house is supplied with 230 V, 50 Hz AC signal and the sockets are three hole ones where the right is for live, left is for neutral and the above hole for ground.

Now if I use a tester and put it in the live hole, the tester glows (of course I need to put my finger on the back side of it, because I act as low voltage)

Now my question is:

Does the AC signal flow backwards i.e from ground (earth surface) to the socket?

It looks silly but please clear my confusion.

Comment: VTC - This question has nothing to do with the design of electronics circuits and is thus off topic here.

Comment: This is a valid question about the use of an electrical tool, and how it works.  I think it should be left open.  At worst, closed as a duplicate if someone can find one of the earlier questions about phase testers.

Answer (score 0):

Neutral and ground in the socket are connected together in the breaker box in the house.  Ground is then connected to the literal ground beneath your feet.

You are connected to the ground - you are standing on it.  Even if you are standing on the floor of your house, it is still connected to the ground.

So, you touch the button the end of the tester.  You touch the other end to the live wire in the socket.  Current flows out of the live wire, though the tester (which lights up,) through you, through the floor, through the ground, through the house ground wire, then from there to the neutral, completing the circuit.

---

There are two things you need to remember when using a phase tester:

1. **YOU** are part of the circuit - this makes some people very nervous.  The current involved is very low, and the resistor in the tester is a carbon composition type that will fail open if it goes bad.  You cannot get shocked unless there is an extremely high voltage on the live wire - which could only be the case if the step down transformer feeding your house is defective.
2. If the ground connection through you is poor, then it will not show a live connection. This can be the case if you are standing on dry concrete or are otherwise well insulated from the ground (thick soled rubber shoes, etc.)

If something happens to cause a high enough voltage to be present that it could shock you, then probably every appliance and light bulb in your house will explode.  So, not a realistic problem.

As for the second point, you **ALWAYS** check first to see that the tester detects the live wire (it **MUST** light up when connected to a known live wire.) Then you turn off the circuit you intend to work on and test again.  If it was on before you shut off the circuit (at the circuit breaker in the switch box) and it was off after you turned off the breaker, then you can be certain that the tester is working and that the power is off.

When the power is off, you can short the live and ground to be doubly certain.  Nothing at should happen if the power is off.  If the power was still on, the short circuit will trip breaker and the power go off for sure.

Comment: My doubt was ,in any AC circuit the current flows in both the directions i.e alternately for each half cycle. Now what about the tester case? It is connected to the ac source itself that means for first half cycle the current passes from live wire to ground via the tester then what about the second half cycle?

Comment: Current flows the same in both directions. Yes, it reverses direction for each half cycle.  The same thing happens in all the devics that use AC.  Half a cycle one direction, half a cycle in the other.

Comment: In all other devices the live wire and neutral wire are part of the same system so it is ok,but here (tester case) we have the live wire and the ground how can you say that still AC current is passing ,as it follows only one direction?

Comment: Ground (and the dirt ground) are connected together, and are connected to neutral.

Comment: Ok I got it, now the question is led  shouldn't glow in opposite direction ,but why does it happen (as the frequency is less it should be quite perceivable right)

Comment: Testers don't use an LED. They use a neon lamp that glows regardless of which way the current flows.